# How to get free horizontal space width left in box

Tags: boxes, rules

I have a box 6cm width, and I want to put there a label followed with underlined area which should fill all horizontal space left. How to make it properly?

```
\makebox[6cm]{
  Label: \underline{
   \makebox[<100% of free space>]{Signature}
  }\newline
}
```

Comment: Is `\makebox[6cm]{Label: \hrulefill}` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bigstrut} 

\begin{document}

\fbox{%
\parbox{6cm}{
  Label: Signature\\[3ex]
\hphantom{Label: }\hrulefill
}}\bigskip

or \bigskip

\fbox{%
\parbox{6cm}{
  Label: \hfill Signature\hfill\null\\[3ex]
\hphantom{Label: }\hrulefill
}}\bigskip
```

or \bigskip

```
\fbox{%
\parbox{6cm}{\bigstrut
  Label: \hrulefill\\[3ex]
\hphantom{Label: }\hfill Signature\hfill\null
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but line should be right above of Signature. Like in
   `\fbox{%
   \parbox{6cm}{
     Label: \hfill Signature\hfill\null\\[-2ex]
   \hphantom{Label: }\hrulefill
   }}`

Comment: That was not clear.  I've updated my answer (leaving the other possibilities since someone might be interested in the other layouts). Is that more like you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a multitude of ways. Here's one using a fixed-width `p`-column in `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\signature}[2][6cm]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{} p{#1} @{} }
    #2:~ & \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & \centering\footnotesize Signature
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\signature{Stan}

\signature[7cm]{Cartman}

\signature{Kyle}

\signature[40mm]{Kenny}

\end{document}
```

If you want to specify the full width of whatever length you specify, you can use a [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) definition:

[image]

```
\newcommand{\signature}[2][6cm]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{#1}{@{} l @{} X @{} }
    #2:~ & \\
    \cline{2-2}
    &\centering\footnotesize Signature
  \end{tabularx}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the label and then make a tabular as wide as the available space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\signaturelabelbox}

\newcommand{\signature}[2][6cm]{%
  \makebox[#1]{%
    \sbox{\signaturelabelbox}{#2: }%
    \usebox{\signaturelabelbox}%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \makebox[\dimexpr#1-\wd\signaturelabelbox]{}\\
    \hline
    \footnotesize\strut Signature
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\signature{Author}

\signature{Advisor}

\signature[10cm]{Author}

\signature[10cm]{Advisor}

\end{document}
```

You're responsible for the vertical spacing (which could be added to the macro).

[image]